# Windows visio pngs can't be opened on linux

Tags: linux, png

I have a PNG image created from VISIO under windows which I tried to use in LaTeX. However, **every** linux program (LaTeX, Okular, GimP) claims the file is corrupted, however, it shows up fine in Chrome. Is there a way to convert the images (preferably in linux) so that LaTeX, Okular and Gimp understand the file?

Currently on Centos 7, with libpng and libpng12 installed.

[image]

Attempt with `convert`:

```
convert nn_generic_cell.png nn_generic_cell_converted.png  
convert: Invalid palette \`nn_generic_cell.png' @ error/png.c MagickPNGErrorHandler/1751. 
convert: corrupt image \`nn_generic_cell.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3789.  
convert: no images defined \`nn_generic_cell_converted.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3046.
```

Comment: Do you have imagemagic's `convert` program?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I am not familiar with convert, but I guessed parameters and as you can see in the updated question, it did not work.

Comment: Is exporting to a different format an option, like TIFF? It sounds like Visio is producing garbage PNGs. You might also try exporting the diagram as PDF or eps, if you can -- I use PDF diagrams with pdflatex, and regular LaTeX should be able to consume eps.

Answer (score 0):

While the reasons are obscure to me, the PNGs created by Visio seem to be broken according to `libpng`. Opening the Visio PNGs in paint and saving them again solves the issue.